# window.print() doesn't print entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

i'm trying to print a newly opened window by using `window.print()`.

My problem is, that only the *start* part of the page is being printed (only what you see when you are scrolled to top-left of the window).

Here is my code:

```
var printWindow = window.open("", "Print", "width=" + nWidth + "px, height=" + nHeight+ "px");
printWindow.document.write(sSvgData, sDivData);
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.print();
```

Solutions i already tried, but didnt work for me:

1) writing the entire html to document (using `window.document.write()`) and including my `css` in header

```
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="print"/></head> 
<body>...

style.css:
@media print {
  body, html, div, #wrapper {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
  }
}
```

2) same as 1) but including the style inline as in:

```
<html><style>@media print { body, html, #wrapper { height: 100%; width: 100%;} }</style><body>...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window in JavaScript refers to the visible window only. As in, whatever is visible on the screen.

1) One way out would be to scroll and print each page individually.

2) Other way would be to use a @media css but then you need to set div tag also to height 100%.

```
@media print {
      body, html, div, #wrapper {
          height: 100%;
      }
}
```

If this also doesn't work, please inspect the page in a browser and check out for all the tags. Some websites use  tags or other tags so you need to see what all tags are there in the website you're trying to print and add all of them to the same css print style.

Also, try if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/nAFSN/1/

**EDIT:** I have also spent a considerable amount of time scratching my head around it long time back and I strongly recommend using a pdf. Try creating a pdf of the content and sending that back to the user when they click on print. This way, you will have more control over how and what to show on each page.

Comment: Tried this, entire page basically only consists of html, body, svg, div's.
So i added div and svg both to the css, now it suggests printing more pages (usually its only 1) but the rest of the pages are all empty

Comment: Unrelated but maybe can you try creating a pdf of the content and sending that back to the user when they click on print? This way, you will have more control over how and what to show on each page.

Comment: Honestly seems like the best way, yeah. I'm not finding any other way either